# Webform CiviCRM Payment on Page 1 of Webform?

Tags: webform-civicrm

Is it possible on any version of Webform CiviCRM, D7, Webform Civicrm?

The profile, amounts, payment - all on one page.

Ironically, we want to go back to 1 page form after users complain of "too many clicks".

Note:
civicrm_1_membership_1_membership_fee_amount is a number field with https://www.drupal.org/project/sliderfield as the widget, which could be the culprit

Edit: I deleted the page break, and it does not show the updated "line item" amounts when the user makes choices. Any way around that?

Edit, just to think out loud, if we could get a native form-builder version of our membership pages with some custom widgets available, that would also be a way to solve this perhaps?